# Versuchsteilnehmende oder Versuchsteilnehmer

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Ich lese zur Zeit eine Bachelor-Arbeit durch und bin häufiger auf den Begriff "Versuchsteilnehmende" gestoßen. Ich bin nun ein wenig verunsichert, ob dies eine leicht andere Bedeutung hat und auch existiert, oder es eigentlich "Versuchsteilnehmer" heißen soll.

Kontext: Ich bin Muttersprachler ':)

Vielen Dank im voraus für die Hilfestellungen.

Comment: *Eigentlich* sollte es auch nicht "Versuchsteilnehmer" sondern "Probanden" heißen ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Einige sehen die Notwendigkeit die deutsche Sprache zu gendern, d.h. darauf zu achten nicht nur das generische Maskulinum zu verwenden. Im Zuge dessen wird das Partizip Präsens verwendet und daraus ein Substantiv geformt.

Teilnehmer -> teilnehmen -> teilnehmend -> Teilnehmende

Die Bedeutung ist identisch*.

Weitere häufige Konstruktionen sind Lehrende und Studierende.

*nach einigen Spitzfindigkeiten in den Kommentaren. Im Kontext, ist die Bedeutung hier identisch. Im Allgemeinen jedoch nicht.

Comment: Vielen Dank für die Antwort und Erklärung

Comment: Naja, die Bedeutung ist eben nicht identisch. Wenn die Teilnehmenden eines Versuchs in der Kneipe sitzen, findet der Versuch offenbar in der Kneipe statt. Das Partizip drückt nämlich aus, dass die Tätigkeit (in diesem Falle des Teilnehmens) gleichzeitig zum Prädikat (also das Sitzen in der Kneipe) stattfindet.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich könntest du deine Anmerkung etwas weiter ausführen? Ich verstehe nämlich nicht was du damit sagen möchtest.

Comment: @puck, ich habe es ja eigentlich schon gesagt: die Tätigkeit im Partizip Präsenz findet zur gleichen Zeit statt wie die Tätigkeit des Prädikats. Anderes Beispiel: *Gestern wurden drei Singende beerdigt.* Das heißt eben nicht, dass drei Sänger beerdigt wurden, sondern drei Personen, die zur Zeit ihrer eigenen Beerdigung sangen. https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partizip_Pr%C3%A4sens_Aktiv

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Aber wenn die Studie mehrtägig ist, sind doch auch die in der Kneipe Sitzenden Teilnehmende?

Comment: Was ist das denn jetzt mit einer Kneipe zu tun?

Comment: @infinitezero, es war ja nur ein Beispiel, das verdeutlichen soll, dass die Bedeutungen nicht immer gleich sind.

Comment: @DavidVogt, in dem speziellen Falle könnte man das so sehen. Aber es geht ja darum, ob die Bedeutungen immer und uneingeschränkt identisch sind – und das sind sie eben nicht.

Comment: Könnte man schreiben "20 Busfahrende sanken mit der Andrea Doria", wenn 20 Busfahrer gemeint sind? Ich meine nein, weil sie zum Zeitpunkt des Sinkens, erst recht nicht zum Zeitpunkt des Schreibens, einen Bus fuhren. Busfahrer ist ein Beruf, Busfahrender der, der eben einen Bus fährt. Versuche sind meist abgeschlossen, wenn  eine Bachelorarbeit von ihnen berichtet. Versuchsteilnehmender ist auch der Versuchsleiter und Assistenten, weil sie am Versuch teilnehmen. Die Begrifflichkeit ist ein Artefakt, um grammatisch klingende Sätze zu formuliern, die gewachsene Bedeutung torpedierend.

Comment: Demnach ist ein Versuchsleiter auch ein Versuchsteilnehmer.

Comment: In dem Falle würde ich Busführende benutzen.

Comment: Analog kann ich in diesem Kontext auch sagen: bei einem Versuch ist wichtig, ob die Versuchsplanung das Geschlecht der Teilnehmer korrekt berücksichtigt (je nach Kontext kann das das biologische Geschlecht, das soziale Geschlecht oder beide sein). Nachdem das klar ist (oder zu allermindest über die Geschlechterverteiung berichtet wurde) ist unmissverständlich welches oder welche Geschlechter das generische "Teilnehmer" umfasst.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich nachdem ich deinen Kneipen Satz jetzt zum 10. Mal gelesen habe, dämmert mir erst, was du damit sagen willst. Ich denke, wenn man im Kontext liest, ist es eindeutig, was gemeint ist. Man kann natürlich immer alles auf die Goldwaage legen, aber wie hilfreich das ist und ob man deswegen Texte umschreiben oder expliziter schreiben sollte - sei mal dahingestellt. Es ist ja kein Mathe- oder Juradokument.

Answer (score 1):

Nach meinem Sprachgefühl ist es zunächst richtig, zwischen den beiden Ausdrücken ("Versuchsteilnehmer"/"Versuchsteilnehmende") einen Bedeutungsunterschied zu vermuten, etwa: Die Substantivform drückt eine Identität aus (Teilnehmer vor oder nach dem Versuch), das Partizip betont die gerade andauernde Tätigkeit (Person, die gerade am Versuch teilnimmt, anstatt gelangweilt aus dem Fenster zu sehen).

Aber in diesem Umfeld darf man annehmen, dass eine "gendergerechte" Formulierung aus einer politischen Auffassung heraus gewählt wurde: Das Partizip Präsens lässt keinen Zweifel, dass das Wort als Utrum gemeint ist (Die Interpretation als nichtgenerische Form ist hier unmöglich, also sind bestimmt nicht nur Frauen oder nur Männer gemeint.), dagegen kann ein generisch gemeintes Maskulinum immer als exklusives Maskulinum mitgelesen werden (Ob mit dem grammatikalischen Maskulinum tatsächlich alle Geschlechter gemeint sind oder nur das männliche, lässt sich nicht allein aus der Grammatik, sondern nur mit Kontext bewerten.).

Welche politische Relevanz in der Entscheidung zugunsten der einen oder anderen Form mitwirkt, hängt u.a. von der jeweiligen Wortbedeutung und dem Millieu der Adressaten (und Adressatinnen) ab:

- Die Frage wird m.E. bei positiv besetzten Begriffen wie "Versuchsteilnehmer"/"-ende" kritischer bewertet als bei negativ besetzten wie "Versuchsabbrecher"/"-ende".
- Die Fundstelle des Begriffs (Bachelorarbeit) weist auf den akademischen Bereich. In diesem wird die eindeutige Addressierung aller mitgemeinten Geschlechter oft als wichtig/kritisch bewertet. Ein Gegenbeispiel wären "Veranstaltungsteilnehmer", die sich vielleicht aus einer bekannt konservativ eingestellten Gruppe, oder einer Gruppe mit höherem Altersdurchschnitt oder geringerem Bildungsstand rekrutieren (sollen). In solchen Gruppen kann die Sensibilität hinsichtlich gendergerechter Sprache geringer oder gar nicht ausgeprägt sein.

Comment: Das ist nicht richtig. Ein generisch gemeintes Maskulinum kann gerade nicht als exklusives Maskulinum gelesen werden. Ohne die Kennzeichnung "männliche Versuchsteilnehmer" ist der Begriff immer generisch. So wie "Katzen" solange generisch  verstanden werden muss, wie sich aus dem Kontext nicht das Gegenteil ergibt (Katzenfutter, Katzenstreu). Frauen sind durch den Begriff "Versuchsteilnehmer" nicht nur am Rande irgendwie mitgemeint, sondern genauso gemeint wie Männer. Es ist gerade keine Sensibilität für Sprache, sondern Verblendung.

Comment: Ich habe ja deutlich auf die politische Dimension der Frage, was wie aufzufassen sei und wie sehr das vom Publikum abhängig ist, hingewiesen. Soweit ich weiß, fokussiert sich dieses Forum auf sprachlichen Fragen und beschäftigt sich mit politischen Hintergründen nur soweit unvermeidbar. Die Bewertung dieser Fragestellung zwischen "Verblendung" und "Sensibilität" hängt eben stark vom pers.Standpunkt ab, ich beobachte zudem eine Abhängigkeit vom Millieu, s.o.

Die Bez. als "generisches" Maskulinum zeigt ja, dass diese Form (auch ohne "männliche") eben auch mal für "nur männliche" stehen kann.

Comment: Nein, eine Form kann nicht gleichzeitig das allgemeine und das besondere markieren. Es ist generisch, so wie "die Katze" für die Hauskatze und die Großkatze steht. Aus dem Kontext kann sich ergeben, dass nur von Hauskatzen die Rede ist, ohne explizit jedes Mal "Hauskatze" zu sagen. Dann markiert der Kontext was gemeint ist, nicht das Wort. Das Wort bleibt generisch, auch wenn es nur für eine Teilmenge benutzt wird.

Comment: Außerdem behaupte ich, dass gerade der Versuch die Frage unpolitisch, nämlich evidenzbasiert, nicht legendenbasiert, zu antworten, wiederum politisch ist. Es lässt sich eben zeigen, dass die Auffassungen von sog. geschlechtergerechter Sprache mit den Fakten in Konflikt steht. Sie ist nicht empfindsam für Nuancen der Sprache, sondern geht vielmehr stoisch über jede Regung von Zweifel hinweg. Die Ideologie wird der Realität aufgezwängt.

Answer (score 0):

Beim  Begriff **Versuchsteilnehmende** wird eine ganz normale grammatisch korrekte Möglichkeit, Versuchsteilnehmende Frauen und Männer zu bezeichnen, gewählt. Es sind somit weibliche wie auch männliche Teilnehmer gemeint. Dasselbe wie VersuchsteilnehmerInnen.
Bei **Versuchsteilnehmer** können weibliche wie auch männliche Teilnehmer gemeint sein. Jedoch müsste man DIE Versuchsteilnehmer schreiben, denn bei *DER Versuchsteilnehmer* wäre nur ein männlicher Teilnehmer gemeint. Für die weibliche Form wäre es *die Versuchsteilnehmerin*.

Comment: Da ich selbst Versuche durchführe, kann ich Ihnen versichern, dass ich nicht nur die männlichen Teilnehmer meine, zumal die überwiegende Anzahl meiner Teilnehmer weiblich ist. Stichworte: generisches Maskulinum, grammatisches versus biologisches Geschlecht.

Comment: Das stimmt nicht. "Der Versuchsteilnehmer" kann generische Einzahl sein, wenn es auf das Geschlecht nicht ankommt, zum Beispiel wenn man das Geschlecht nicht kennt. Das männliche Geschlecht, soweit es sich nicht aus dem Kontext ergibt, muss man ausdrücklich dazu schreiben, wie Du es ja selbst tust: "Der männliche Versuchsteilnehmer bekommt ein blaues Bändchen".